# css3 hover on icon and border

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML CODE...

```
          <ul class="social-icon">
            <li><a href="#" class="social-facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook ff"></i>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-rss"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
```

And CSS CODE..

```
.social-icon {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .social-icon li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    .social-icon li a {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 28px;
      width: 35px;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
      height: 36px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .social-icon li a:first-child {
      border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .social-icon li a .ff {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: scale(5);
      -moz-transform: scale(5);
      -o-transform: scale(5);
      -ms-transform: scale(5);
      transform: scale(5);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    }
    .social-icon li a .ff:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: #345599;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -o-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
      -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
      -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
      -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    .social-icon li a i {
      color: #d2d2db;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
    }
```

The problem is when i hover on fb icon it's background color was little. And the border is double i use 1px border.. Please help me...Sorry for my bad English.

[Here is jsFiddle editor link](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/42/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you want:

```
.social-icon {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-icon li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
}
.social-icon li a{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 36px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.social-icon li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.social-icon li .ff {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
  -o-transform: scale(5);
  -ms-transform: scale(5);
  transform: scale(5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.social-icon li .ff:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #345599;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.social-icon li a i {
  color: #d2d2db;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.social-icon .fa-facebook {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

EDIT: I updated the code. There will still be the problem of the `.ff` object being much larger than the `<li>` container. So you will activate the transition in spaces outside of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like:

```css
.social-icon li a .ff:hover
{
    display: block; 
    width: 37px; 
    height: 32px;
}

.social-icon li a i
{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #d2d2db;
    position: absolute
}
```

Comment: this hover effect is one icon is static position and one icon is animated. look like this,, http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/26/ but using 2 icon

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?  Change your css to the following...

```
.social-icon {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-icon li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.social-icon li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.social-icon li :hover{
  background-color: #345599;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.social-icon li a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.social-icon li a .ff {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
  -o-transform: scale(5);
  -ms-transform: scale(5);
  transform: scale(5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.social-icon li a .ff:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.social-icon li a i {
  color: #d2d2db;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

I added the class **.social-icon li :hover**

I also added the property **background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);** to the class **.social-icon li a .ff:hover**

Answer (score 0):

Your first-child selector is not correct. It selects every element of the list. That is why you have double borders.

Your background hover selects only `<i>` and not the entire `<a>`. Hence, it appears small.

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/64/

HTML:

```
<ul class="social-icon">
    <li><a href="#" class="social-facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>        
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-twitter">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-google-plus">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-dribbble">
            <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-linkedin">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="social-rss">
            <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.social-icon {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-icon li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.social-icon li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 36px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.social-icon li:first-child a {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

/* Facebook colour */
.social-icon li a.social-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #345599;
}

.social-icon li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.social-icon li a i {
  color: #d2d2db;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But i use two icon in same position. Thank you very much.